# HTTPS tunnel from CDN - parsing remote IP from TCP options, in software

Tags: sockets, amazon-web-services, tcp

We're working with an edge network provider that is TCP proxying HTTPS traffic from their edge servers to our systems. Because traffic is under HTTPS and thus unmodifiable, they're storing the IP in the TCP header, in option #22. We need to get access to the client IP out of that header to use in our app.

Their suggestion is to buy an F5 load balancer. We don't exactly have a rack to put it in (AWS shop). So we're looking for a software solution--something that can terminate SSL *and* do the requisite magic to synthesize an X-Forwarded-For or an X-Real-IP header out of that TCP option. I don't even have the faintest clue where to go from here to get to that, though (especially if we have to write our own).

Any suggestions, AWS or just software, would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you get this information in an easy way. Some ideas:

- you could try to use raw sockets, but it would be slow and complex
- you might try to write a kernel module which then provides you the necessary information with a getsockopt call
- you might try to use netlink (NFLOG) target with iptables to forward the relevant SYN packets to user space (with full IP+TCP header) and then you could extract the relevant information and apply them to the matching TCP connection (e.g. the one was same source + dst ip+port)

In any case there will be probably some non-trivial coding necessary.